# How to align text inside list view to the right instead of the default left?

Tags: nativescript

I am creating an Arabic app with NativeScript. I want each row inside list view to be viewed in rtl direction so the text in the row is aligned to the right.

I tired using text-align:right and horizontal-align:right but didn't worked.
How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no code snippet of what you have tried so far we can only speculate what is your code structure.([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))
However here is a very basic example on how to align all list-view cell templates to the right by default.

```
<ListView.itemTemplate>
    <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*">
            <Label row="0" col="0" text="right aligned text" textAlignment="right" textWrap="true" /> 
    </GridLayout>
</ListView.itemTemplate>
```